# ht access link to pdf

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ive a site with links in the page which lives in root are of the format:

/documents/mimecast-email_continuity_whitepaper.pdf
(correct physical path)

but by the time it comes out in the browser results in the following error (naming the correct path)

"This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage at name-of-website/documents/Comtec-Relocations-Case-Study-v4.pdf has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Learn more about this problem.

Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects."

The rule Ive put in is

-.htaccess (in file)---------- (in my root directory - where all the web pages live)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(pdf)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://dev.comtec.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(edited as my first question wasnt very clear apologies)

Appreciate any thoughts

K

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not run on my site"? Does it give a syntax error? Isn't is processed? Does it do unexpected things? Does the universe explode?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not being more obvious apologies. 

What I mean is:

website of this structure
root - all php files (inc resources.php)
documents (is a directory with all the pdf documents in it)

A link within "resources.php" with the path of: 

website-address/documents/Economic-Impact-of-Cisco-UCS-A-Forrester-Report.pdf

resolves to:

website/resources.php/Economic-Impact-of-Cisco-UCS-A-Forrester-Report.pdf

It adds in the name of the file which contains the link 
and removes the directory the file actually lives in 

so its erroring with file not found.

Hope that makes more sense.

K

Comment: Sorry, no, this does not make more sense. 1.) you did not answer my question, why? and 2.) instead of that lengthy, hard to read comment it would make more sense if you _edit_ your question above and try to put in more details and make it more clear what your situation is, what you want to happen and ehat exactly it is that does not work.